# Pandas read_csv only first comma

Tags: python, string, pandas, csv, multiple-columns

I have a csv database that looks like this:

```
Date,String
2010-12-31,'This, is, an example string'
2011-12-31,"This is an, example string"
2012-12-31,This is an example, string
```

I am trying to use pandas, because I believe it is one of the most widespread libraries to working with this kind of situations. Is there a way to create a DataFrame taking into account only the first comma using the `read_csv` function? (regardless of the fact that the string after has "" or '' or nothing to isolate it).

If not, what's the most efficient alternative to do so?

Thanks so much in advance for any help,

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can cheat by passing a regex for the `sep` argument of `read_csv`. The regex I used is `^([^,]+),` which grabs the first comma. I also used the `engine` argument in order to avoid a pandas warning (since the default C engine does not support a regex sep) and the `usecols` argument to make sure we only get the columns we want (without it we also get an "unnamed" column, I'm not sure why to be honest).

You can get more information about each argument in [`read_csv` docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html).

test.csv

```
Date,String
2010-12-31,'This, is, an example string'
2011-12-31,"This is an, example string"
2012-12-31,This is an example, string
```

Then

```
print(pd.read_csv('test.csv', sep='^([^,]+),', engine='python', usecols=['Date', 'String']))
```

Outputs

```
         Date                         String
0  2010-12-31  'This, is, an example string'
1  2011-12-31   "This is an, example string"
2  2012-12-31     This is an example, string
```

**This will not work if you will have more than 2 "actual" columns in the CSV file**

Comment: You get an unnamed column because your separator is at the beginning of the line, so there is a blank column to the left of your line (exactly as if you had a csv file with lines like ,foo,bar)